# webRTC not able to connect pier when force to use TURN server

Tags: websocket, webrtc, stun, turn

I am using basic webRTC setup using github : https://github.com/jkithome/simple-webrtc-chat-app

I am able to run locally, and able to connect 2 instances of webRTC. As local webRTC doesn't need TURN or STUN server. But when i force using "iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'". Both instances are able to create "offer","candidate". But not able to start dataChannel. Exact same code works fine if remove ""iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'".

Here is the code use to force to use TURN server.

```
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'turn:TURN_SERVER',
      username: 'USERNAME',
      credential: 'PASSWORD'
    }
  ],
  iceTransportPolicy: 'relay' // Force the use of TURN server
};
```

I am using free TURN server provided by metered. Even after multiple tries not able to run it.

I tried looking into webRTC tutorials, but all are explaining very basic webRTC connectivity . Which doesn't use TURN server.